# How to Convert List[Any] into a preparedStatement for jdbc

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, match

I have a list of Any values and a sql preparedStatement. I want to set values on the preparedStatement in scala. My issue is the setNull method on the prepared statement requires you to specify the type on the null value and I can't access what type the null is in my match expression. Below is my code:

```
  def executePreparedStatement(preparedStatement: PreparedStatement, values: List[Any], startIndex: Int = 0): PreparedStatement = {
    for ((value, index) <- values.zipWithIndex) {
      value match {
        case x: String => {
          preparedStatement.setString(index + startIndex, x)
          preparedStatement
        }
        case x: Boolean => {
          preparedStatement.setBoolean(index + startIndex, x)
          preparedStatement
        }
        case x: Int => {
          preparedStatement.setInt(index + startIndex, x)
          preparedStatement
        }
        case x: Float => {
          preparedStatement.setFloat(index + startIndex, x)
          preparedStatement
        }
        case Some(x) => executePreparedStatement(preparedStatement, x :: values.tail, index)
        case None => executePreparedStatement(preparedStatement, null :: values.tail, index)
        case null => {
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR)
        }
```

You can see the last line above I just set the type to VARCHAR but it could be anything. How should I specify it, or is there a better way to write a similar function given a sql string and a List of Any values?

Comment: did you tried the `NULL` type? Please find this link. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html, here we have `NULL` type also

Comment: Not all DB accept `setNull` w/o specific type. P.S. `Any` is generally a symptom of bad design.